# Pandas's `pct_change()` equivalent in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Let's assume I have a table like this:

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-05 | 100 |
| 1 | 2021-04-04 | 50 |
| 1 | 2021-04-03 | 25 |
| 1 | 2021-04-02 | 5 |
| 2 | 2021-04-05 | 80 |
| 2 | 2021-04-04 | 20 |
| 2 | 2021-04-03 | 15 |
| 2 | 2021-04-02 | 10 |

I need to add another column that groups by `id` and calculates a day-over-day percent change from the value with the date before it. So for this example it would look like this:

| id | date | value | pct_change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-05 | 100 | 100 |
| 1 | 2021-04-04 | 50 | 100 |
| 1 | 2021-04-03 | 25 | 400 |
| 1 | 2021-04-02 | 5 | NaN |
| 2 | 2021-04-05 | 80 | 300 |
| 2 | 2021-04-04 | 20 | 33.33 |
| 2 | 2021-04-03 | 15 | 50 |
| 2 | 2021-04-02 | 10 | NaN |

In python this would be easy, I could do something like this:

```
df['pct_change'] = df.groupby('id').value.pct_change() * 100
```

But if I wanted to do this in the Postgres database call, I'd suddenly implode with stupidity... does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for `LAG...OVER`, like this? https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lag-function/

Comment: Yes, this is helpful. I'm now much closer but for some reason the percent change is not calculating correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT 
id, 
date,
value, 
(value - prev_value) / prev_value AS pct_change
FROM
(
SELECT 
id, 
date, 
value,
LAG(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date 
                              ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 
                                           CURRENT ROW) AS prev_value
FROM
your_table
)
ORDER BY date, id
```